# DefaultIfEmpty Exception "bug or limitation" with EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

I tried to execute the following code:

```
await _dbContext.Customers.Select(x => x.CustomerNr).DefaultIfEmpty(0).MaxAsync() + 1;
```

Essentially it has to get the highest customer number from the database and add 1 to it. If the customer table is empty, it should return 0 to which I add 1. Why is it giving me the following exception:

[image: Linq error message]

**Edit:**
I am using .NET Core 3.1 and EF Core 3.0.1 (Same error for EF Core 3.1.0)

Comment: What's your version of .NET Core and EF Core?

Comment: I editet my question @V0ldek

Comment: This may seem superfluous, but what happens if you wrap the `( await ... .MaxAsync() ) + 1` in parens.

Comment: Same error. seems like an EF error to me... Same error for EF Core 3.1.0 @ErikPhilips

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Avoid `DefaultIfEmpty` overload with default value - it's not supported by EF Core query translator.

Also in general avoid `DefaultIfEmpty` parameterless overload for anything else than left outer join pattern because while it is supported, SQL translation is quite weird.

To solve the problem with applying `Max`, `Min` and `Average` methods on empty sets, use the nullable overloads which return `null` for empty set, and convert `null` result to 0 (or other desired magic value) if needed.

Applying it to your scenario would be somethong like this (assuming the `CustomerNr` type is `int`):

```
(await _dbContext.Customers.MaxAsync(x => (int?)x.CustomerNr)) ?? 0 + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! Weird that DefaultIfEmpty is not supported by EF Core though. Seems like a pretty basic function to me...